# XML Transformation - Remove line break after xml declaration

Tags: xml, xslt

After a XML Transformation, I get the following result :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:[..]><Tag1></tag1><Tag2></Tag2>[..]</Document>
```

I need the output file to be on a single line,
like the following :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:[..]><Tag1></tag1><Tag2></Tag2>[..]</Document>
```

The only one solution that worked up to this date is to not display the declaration, but I'd rather not do that if there is an alternative.

My XSL template start like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
                [...]
                xmlns:bpm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn20/extensions"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension">

  <xsl:decimal-format name="decdot" decimal-separator="."/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Document>
      [...]
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use  `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and `<xsl:output indent="no"/>`

Comment: @AmrendraKumar: This seems to depend on the XSLT processor you're using. With `xsltproc`(XSLT-1.0) it doesn't work and with Saxon(XSLT-3.0) it does work as desired. So it seems to be a border case of the specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that looks more of rubber tape than an actual fix to me, but it works just fine, does that seems legit to you ?

I decided to ommit declaration and then to force the transformation to write it down manually via code like this :

```xml
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?></xsl:text>
    <Document>
      [...]
    </Document>
  </template>
```

Comment: It's a hack that shouldn't be necessary. Which XSLT processor are you using? -- P.S. Note that whitespace *should* be insignificant, and the XML declaration is optional - so if you must have this, the real problem is with the target application.

Comment: On my side, while developping i'm only using the XML Tools of notepad++, in the end the XML transformation is processed by BI Publisher (Oracle software).

Both encountered the same "issue" for my demander.

Comment: I don't know about BI Publisher. With a Microsoft processor, you *should* be getting the same result as the one here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh2J

Answer (score 0):

For the solution I'm omiting the namespaces of the XML used.

For this I would just a copy of all the content via XPath 1.0 and force said copy of the XML without the indenting and formating of the XSLT stylesheet.

### XML Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:[..]"><Tag1></Tag1><Tag2></Tag2></Document>
```

### XSLT 1.0 Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="no" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="decdot" decimal-separator="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### XML Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:[..]"><Tag1/><Tag2/></Document>
```

Comment: If I get what you mean, you are using a second transformation over the first one ?

(what you put in XML Input, is what I presently get from my transformation)
the original XML has nothing to do with that, tag and architecture have different names in a different achitecture)